# Python Storing Breakpoint Variable State in Cython File - sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython, pdb

I want to take snapshots of a few variables when sklearn.tree got built but had a hard time got it working.

For example, behind these following lines of code.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)   <-- tree builder recursively build the tree
```

However, the exact implementation for that part is done in Cython (speed). Usually, I would use tools like pdb to set a breakpoint in my code and maybe use `display` command to track the variables of my interest. However, this approach doesn't look realistic as I easily got lost when navigating through files.

```
(python37) $ python script.py 
> /private/tmp/test/script.py(6)<module>()
-> clf = clf.fit(X, y)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/a59347/Desktop/scikit-learn/sklearn/tree/tree.py(852)fit()
-> def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, check_input=True,
(Pdb) 
> /Users/a59347/Desktop/scikit-learn/sklearn/tree/tree.py(888)fit()
-> super().fit(
(Pdb) 
...      <- I easily got lost and ended up in a very low level utility library
```

Is there a way to add a breakpoint to [this line of code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L258) in Python? 
I am literally interested in how the whole stack got changed during the tree building process:

```
 while not stack.is_empty():
     stack.pop(&stack_record)
     start = stack_record.start
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to actually get the source of scikit-learn from their Github repo, [import the library](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial) locally using perhaps PYTHONPATH, then use standard [Cython debugging tools to debug](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html).

Honestly though I think you'll get more mileage by studying the algorithm, and asking a question in the sklearn devlist/Github repo if you're interested.

If I were to guess what's happening there, since you're looking at the depth-first growing algorithm:

- Put all data into a single node, the root.
- Find the best splitting criterion to split the data, using a metric like information gain.
- Split the data into two parts, using the criterion. Create right and left child, each gets one split of the data.
- Recurse the above algorithm into right child, then the left.

This is a recursive process, and the devs have used a stack to make it iterative.